# Is it common for children to say "times" when pausing play?

Tags: american-english, slang

When I was a child on the American west coast, my circle of friends would always say "times!" to suspend play and talk out of character, or otherwise suspend the rules of a game. For example, if we were playing tag, one of us could say "times!" if we got hurt, and the game would stop for a moment.

I assumed that this was a ubiquitous thing, but I was surprised to see just not that neither Merriam-Webster nor Wiktionary documents this usage of the word.

Is this an oversight, or is this a really isolated usage?

Comment: It might have to do with "Time-out" as a word for taking a short break in sports, and could be a slang/colloquialism. However, I used it as a child, and so did my circle of friends, too. Curious what the background on this is.

Comment: I have never heard of this before.

Comment: In Texas in the 1960s (and presumably afterward) it was common for kids to shout "Time!" as a short form of "Time out!" in a game such as tag or baseball so that the applicability of some special rule or some claimed exemption from the normal rules could be hashed out. I believe that "Time!" for "Time out!" is widespread in sports at all levels throughout North America. However, I have not heard "Times!" (plural) used in this sense anywhere I've lived, which includes (for the past 35 years) the San Francisco Bay Area.

Comment: When I was a child in a suburb of London and we played in the road, anyone seeing a vehicle coming would shout “ROTTEN EGGS!, and we would all rush for the pavement (‘sidewalk’).  I have no idea where it came from or who thought it up.  Probably it was an example of private language.

Comment: @Tuffy Northeast American here, and we used expressions like "last one out is a rotten egg." Suggests to me that your usage wasn't particularly localized.

Comment: I used this phrase exactly this way in Texas as a child. You'll have better luck looking in the Dictionary of American Regional English for phrases like this rather than a standard dictionary like MW.

Comment: In Britain in the 1950s we had a word which was similarly used to halt one's involvement in a game - "exxies". (if that is how it is spelled - it doesn't have an entry in the OED.)

Comment: In the US Midwest (Louisville KY area) in the 50s and 60s it was common playground jargon to call "Time!" as short for "Time out!"  I don't recall ever hearing "Times!" in this context.

Comment: East coast usage, "Time's out!" (We were kids; what did we know?) And so the timeout concluded with, "Time's in!"

Comment: I grew up in southern Ontario, Canada and recall "times" being used as you describe in the 1970s; I do not recall having heard it since my childhood though. It would be interesting to ask some children if this is still common.

Comment: We used "Times" and "Time out" in Florida as kids in the 80s and 90s

Comment: In India, we used "time please" in the 90s. Not sure what they say now-a-days.

Comment: @WS2 I was about to comment that in East Anglia, UK in the 1980s I'm certain we had a term but I couldn't remember what it was, you reminded me! I remember there being arguments over legitimate uses vs just trying to get out of being tagged.

Comment: @JosephRogers Yes. East Anglia was my home ground too. So unless someone else pitches in we shall not know whether it was local to our area, or more widespread.

Comment: Note that "time out" and "time's out" mean different things.  The first is a pause in play, as in American football.  The second means that the time on the clock has expired.

Comment: @HotLicks When I was a child, "Time's out" was used the same as "Time out", "Time", and "Time's" to mean a pause in play.  To indicate that the clock had expired, we used "Time's up".

Answer (score 19):

As reported (in a paper called ["Terms used for children’s games", published in the 1996 *Focus on the USA*](https://benjamins.com/catalog/veaw.g16.05sch)) by Luanne von Schneidemesser, based on results from a 1994 survey, for 296 informants ("younger people") responding to "In a game of tag, if a player wants to rest, what does he call out so that he can’t be tagged?" ([*DARE*](https://www.daredictionary.com/) Question EE17),

> *Times* was reported 20 times...*times* has spread as far west as Texas, Oklahoma, Colorado, and Minnesota, as well as one response in Arizona.
>
> [Text as found in [*Dictionary of American Regional English Online*](https://www.daredictionary.com/view/dare/ID_00059338); paywalled.]

The simple exclamation 'times!' is one of several variants. [*DARE*](https://www.daredictionary.com/) supposes the sense is probably "transf[erred] from *time out* a brief suspension of play in var[ious] organized sports (*OED2 time out...*)" (op. cit.).

Of the variants *time(s)*, *times out*, and *times ex* (rare), *DARE* observes that *ex* in the equivalent phrase *king's ex*

> is often assumed to be an abbr[eviation] for *excuse*, [but] it seems more likely that it, as well as *(s)cruce(s)* and *crosses*, refers to the act of crossing the fingers, often an essentail part of claiming a truce or time out.
>
> [From the entry for "king's ex *exclam*, *n*", [*DARE*](https://www.daredictionary.com/view/dare/ID_00033580#ID_00033580) (paywalled).]

In addition to *DARE* and von Schneidemesser's more 'scientific' data collection, commenters at this site (ELU) aver the use of the exclamation 'times!', sometimes accompanied by a 'T' hand gesture, in the children's game sense of "time out" in California (undated, and 1980s) and Nova Scotia (1990s), etc.

Comment: We yelled  *Time!* or  *Time out!* or *I call time!* in southeastern Pennsylvania, near the Twelve Mile Circle.

Comment: As far west as Texas? As a Californian, I can say with absolute certainty it made its way all the way.

Comment: As a kid in the 90s, I said this in Nova Scotia, Canada. So I'd say it's likely fairly widespread.

Comment: My elementary school friends and I in 1980s Southern California definitely called *times* to ask for a pause in play, accompanied with a *T* gesture with our hands to signify a time out, but without prejudice against *time out!*

Comment: I can confirm that it made its way to India (no I'm not missing an 'na') by 2000

Answer (score 1):

The following is for AmE:

This [DARE](https://www.daredictionary.com/view/dare/ID_00059338?rskey=60VYKT&result=4&q=times) survey ( 20 years old! ) supports in AmE > **time out** > **time** > **times**. **times out** = 0.

> 1996 Focus USA: The picture has changed among the younger people
> questioned this year. Sixty-one percent of them [=of 296 total infs]
> responded with **time out**, almost twice the percentage of informants
> found by DARE; 20% said **time**. . . **Times** was reported 20 times, **times
> out** not at all. Time is no longer confined to mostly East Coast
> states, but has spread across the country, while times has spread as
> far west as Texas, Oklahoma, Colorado, and Minnesota, as well as one
> response in Arizona.

Of course, the preponderance of the usage of this is amongst the younger crowd, but in the > 40 y.o. one frequently hears **time out** or **time** in various venues to suggest:

- rest break
- cease discussion
- etc>>>

I have never heard **times** ... in work or play.

Answer (score 0):

In Memphis, Tennessee, in the late 1950s we “called Times.”